# Filling Missing Values in Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Item  ID
NULL  1
NULL  2
3     3
NULL  4
NULL  5
```

Im trying to get the output as

```
Item  ID
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     5
```

using cursors i updated the bottom 2 nulls as 4 and 5 
and using flags i have counted the NULLs above 3 but i cant access the top 2 positions ?
is the approach correct ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear what you're asking for, but `COALESCE` will take multiple parameters, and return the first non-NULL value.

```
SELECT COALESCE(Item, ID)
```

To get both columns, with the column defaulting to the other columns value if it's null, you can do

```
SELECT COALESCE(Item, ID) AS Item,
       COALESCE(ID, Item) AS ID
```

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply. I need to populate the first column with missing values in ascending or descending order (in the example above, i assumed its ascending) .... i used cursors but didnt get the complete answer